# Ubuntu freezes at splash screen (plymouth) after gpu install

Tags: drivers, nvidia, freeze, plymouth, proprietary

I have just installed my new Nvidia GTX 760 and even with the proper (proprietary) drivers installed Ubuntu freezes at the splash screen. If I take out the GPU it's fine. And when I put it in but don't activate it in the bios in Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit loads fine, but the GPU is just being ignored.

So this is what happens when I start the PC with the GPU installed and activated:
The POST-screen appears fine; Plymouth loads; all the dots turn orange; then it freezes.

What can cause this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It's too simple to fix.

Open the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Change...

**GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""** to **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"**

and

**GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""** to **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=splash vga=791**

... And save.

```
sudo update-grub

sudo dpkg-reconfigure linux-image-$(uname -r)

sudo update-initramfs -u
```

And restart the PC.

Good luck!

Comment: the first one is not recognized as a command. And what is it supposed to do? just to know beforehand

Comment: sorry, check the answer now.

Comment: but it is already set to "quiet splash"

Comment: So you need specify the splash resolution. try do set on /etc/default/grub `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=splash vga=791`

Comment: ok, i'll try that, but still I would love to know why. What is the problem, why should that help? Just so I know what to do if this kinda stuff happens again.

Comment: I think that the plymouth (for any reason) cannot defines resolution to splash screen when you are using proprietary drivers, So you need force it (when you define `vga=791`, it's equivalent as 1024x768 for splash screen resolution)

Comment: What I forgot to mention, I don't know if it is important, It is only showing on one screen. But the POST-screen does only show on one either so maybe that's why. But I don't know, can that be linked somehow?

Comment: I don't know, try to choose the the plymouth bootscreen again: `update-alternatives --config default.plymouth`; after check the `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` is ok. to finalize please perform:
`sudo update-grub;
sudo dpkg-reconfigure linux-image-$(uname -r);
sudo update-initramfs -u`;

Please tell us if it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18597/discussion-between-ubuntu-stuff-and-marcos-rocha).

Comment: Did not work. Same problem. Froze just after all the dots changed colour.

Comment: Did not opening the lightdm-greeter screen?

Comment: no, just stopped at plymouth

Comment: Same problem here. Did you ever solve it, @ubuntu.stuff?

Comment: @skaz Nope, I never did.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to boot and don't require a splash because your system actually starting up is more important to you, you can remove the `splash` from the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` or you can add `noplymouth` which will skip the mode switch that tends to cause the hangup, but still might not be very pretty.